# How to untrace multiple functions

Tags: debugging, r, trace

If I have a few interconnected functions, then it can be useful to trace the path through them.  That is using the `trace` function to give a message each time R enters or leaves one of the functions.  For example,

```
f <- function() g()
g <- function() h()
h <- function()
{
 if(runif(1) > 0.3) g() else 99
}

trace_my_fns <- function()
{
  fn_names <- c("f", "g", "h")
  invisible(trace(
    fn_names,
    tracer = quote(0),
    exit   = quote(0),
    where  = globalenv()
  ))
}

trace_my_fns()
set.seed(4)
f()
```

When I'm finished with this tracing, I need to untrace them.

```
untrace_my_fns <- function()
{
  fn_names <- c("f", "g", "h")
  invisible(trace(
    fn_names,
    where = globalenv()
  ))
}
untrace_my_fns()
```

For some reason, this isn't untracing the functions properly.  To see this, take a look at

```
f
body(f)
```

If I directly call untrace on each function, for example `untrace(f)` at the commmand line, it works.  How should I create a function to untrace all my functions at once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, change to:

```
untrace_my_fns <- function()
{
  fn_names <- c("f", "g", "h")
  invisible(untrace(
    fn_names,
    where = globalenv()
  ))
}

untrace_my_fns()
set.seed(4)
f() # no more tracing...
```

...because you called `trace` instead of `untrace`!

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing.  Superbly spotted, thanks.  I'm going to go and have a little falcepalm now.